# Quartz jobdetail from jobkey is null

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have following two methods,

```
initialJob();
otherJobs();
```

Others jobs only need to start once the initial job is complete.

This is the initial job method.

```
private void initialJob(){
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(RestTriggerForQuartzJobs.class)
                          .withIdentity("INITIAL_JOB_NAME", TRIGGER_GROUP)
                          .usingJobData("PARAM", "")
                          .build();               
   Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail).startNow().build();
   scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}
```

Here I am checking if the initial job is completed. If not, calling the same method recursively till it completes

```
private void otherJobs(){
   if(isJobComplete("INITIAL_JOB_NAME")){
   JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(RestTriggerForQuartzJobs.class)
                          .withIdentity("JOB_NAME", TRIGGER_GROUP)
                          .usingJobData("PARAM", "")
                          .build();               
   Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail).startNow().build();
   scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
   }else{
   otherJobs();
   }
}
```

In isComplete Method, jobDetail is getting null for  JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey) eventhough I can see the DEFAULT.INITIAL_JOB_NAME in the quartz triggers table.

```
private Boolean isJobComplete(String jobName) throws SchedulerException {
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName);
        JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey);
        List<? extends Trigger> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobDetail.getKey());
        for (Trigger trigger : triggers) {
            TriggerState triggerState = scheduler.getTriggerState(trigger.getKey());
            if (TriggerState.COMPLETE.equals(triggerState)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: where is `isComplete` method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey)` is returning null because `JobKey` is composed of both name and group in order to uniquely identify a job.

That means you have to initiate your `JobKey` with both name and **group**:

```
private Boolean isJobComplete(String jobName) throws SchedulerException {
    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, TRIGGER_GROUP);
    JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey);
    ...
```

Another tip by the way: Calling the method `otherJobs` recursively an undefined time could lead to a `StackOverflowError`. Maybe [listeners](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07.html) are useful for your use case.